# Update attach users Laravel 5.4 duplicate user already attched

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to update attached user, i have user attach to project, i need to edit project by adding new attach user so my code look like this

```
$project = Project::find($id);
            $project->update($request->all());

           $array = $project->users;
           foreach ($array as $item){
               if($request->input('user_id') != $item->id){
                   Log::info('user new ids: ',[$item->id]);
                   $project->users()->attach($request->input('user_id'));
               }
               else{
                   Log::info('user aleardy attached');
               }
           }

        return response()->json($organisation);
```

This code duplicate users in database i find the same user assign to project several times
Also this code just for attach , so how to resolve this issue and thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looping through each user attached to the project. On each iteration you're checking if the `id` matches the user_id that was submitted. For almost all iterations, this will evaluate to false and the user will be attached again.

For example:
Users `4`,`5`,`6` are attached to the project. `user_id` = `2`.

The loop would result in the following:

`4!=2`, so attach the user.

`5!=2`, so attach the user.

`6!=2`, so attach the user.

As you can see the user will be added 3 times.

I would use something like this:

```
if ($project->users()->where('users.id',$request->input('user_id'))->count()==0){
    Log::info('user new ids: ',[$item->id]);
    $project->users()->attach($request->input('user_id'));
}else{
     Log::info('user aleardy attached');
}
```

The above query will look for any users attached to the project that match the `user_id` submitted. If the count is 0, then the `user_id` is not attached to the project so you can attach it.

Comment: Thanks @Brad i get this error, SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate

Comment: Updated answer. You have to remove ambiguity by specifying the table name (users.id rather than just id)

Comment: still error when i update by removing one user, it still in DB :(

Comment: @Akram your whole logic only deals with attaching a new user. No where you check for any condition and detach users. Update your question to be more precise and provide the information needed to make a conditional check to attach or detach the given user.

Comment: You still haven't defined any condition to detach. Anyway to detach a user just do the inverse of this solution. Change `count() != 0` and `detach($request->input('user_id'));`.

Comment: @Akram you can do it in a single function. But you need some condition to detect if you should attach or detach. That's up to you.